# Laravel validation errors are being displayed in Ajax Success Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

When I submit an Ajax request and I know that the data should fail, I am receiving the error response within the `success` event instead of the `fail` event.

I need the response from Laravel to be sent to the Ajax fail event, as I will be building custom functionality for when the request fails to process.

I've tried all sorts to try and get it to work, but I'm at a complete loss as to why it's returning into the Success event. I must be being daft or something!

My Function within the Controller:

```
    public function add_company(Request $request)
    {

        /**
         * Validate the Add Company request
         */
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'sector' => 'required',
            'number' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Something went wrong']);
        }

        DB::table('companies')->insert([
            'user_id' => Auth::id(), 
            'company_number' => $request->company_number,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'sector' => $request->sector,
            'number' => $request->number,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'address_1' => $request->address_line_1,
            'address_2' => $request->address_line_2,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'postcode' => $request->postcode,
        ]);

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Company created successfully.']);

    }
```

My Ajax function:

```
$('[data-add-company]').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $this = $(this);
    let action = $this.attr('action');
    let method = $this.attr('method');

    var formData = $this.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: action,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data); // Fail messages appear here for some reason.
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

I've tried using `data.success` and `data.error` to get the correct message but they just come up as undefined when I key into them.

**What should happen**

1. The `fail` event should initiate when the validation fails and show the correct fail message from the controller.
2. The `success` event should only contain the success message from the controller, once the request has been successfully validated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DevinNorgarb Hey Devin! The validation throws back errors if the form data is invalid, but those errors are being passed to the Ajax’s success event, not the Ajax’s fail event. Weird, right? The data does not get inserted into the DB if the validation fails, only when the validation passes. It all works fine apart from where these error messages should be sent to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be happening is even though your request failed its validation in the controller its still returns a valid response which JQuery sees as a `success`, allowing it into the `success` callback on the frontend.

Try

```
        if ($validator->fails()) {
           return response()->json(["error" => "something went wrong"], 422);
        }
```

This should trigger the error callback.

You can also pass the errors back like this:

```
          return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
```

To get all the error messages on the frontend.

For further reading check out this jQuery [error handling article](https://thisinterestsme.com/handle-ajax-error-jquery/) .

Comment: For those wondering how to access the error response, I just logged out: `console.log(data.responseJSON.error);` not `data.error`.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance! You might also want to consider using `.done(function(data){})` and `.fail(function(xhr, status, error){})` to access the  response. I will update my answer with an example.